# Encoding a message with Vigenere cipher in Delphi?

Tags: function, delphi, delphi-2010, vigenere

I want to encrypt a message with a simple Vigenere cipher by assigning each letter in the alphabet a numeric value e.g. A= 1; B= 2;..Z= 26. The problem is I don't know which function to use to recognize a character in a string(as it is a message that has to be encoded, complete with spaces), and then giving it a specific, numeric value.

Next up, that numeric message has to be converted into binary, which is easy, but how do I convert that message that was a string into an integer(other that the StrToInt function)?

I just need to know which function to use for the Vigenere Cipher.
*I am still in High school so I apologize in advance for using the wrong terms.

Comment: Well, how is space to be encoded? And what about punctuation? And you should go direct to binary. And this is not encryption.

Comment: I'll use different numerical values for spaces and punctuation, and I have to use both encoding types, because the requirements for this assignment stipulate that.

Comment: Use a case statement, for instance, and map directly to a byte array. I suggest that you make an attempt on your assignment. Or at least make it clear where you are stuck. For instance, do you know how to read the i-th character of a string? Do you know how to make a dynamic array? Do you know what a case statement is? Have you written any code at all yet?

Comment: Okay, I'll use the case statement, but isn't it limited? Will I be able to use 26+ cases?

Comment: Yes, I have written code (don't you think the whole school and assignment thing gave it away?) but I'm a beginner so please bear with me or don't, but in my handbook it says that the case statement is limited.

Comment: You can have as many as you like in a case. You can do A-Z in one go.

Comment: @FreeConsulting YOu should mention that Ord only works with AnsiChars (ansi strings) and not UnicodeChars (Unicode Strings).

Comment: @SilverWarior, why? This statement is not true and will only add more confusion for an OP.

Comment: @Silver What you say is simply not true

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, there is some sense in reducing alphabet to `AnsiChar` (or even to `'A'..'Z'` subrange) for the sake of learning.

Comment: @FreeConsulting Clearly this assignment has taken that stance. Which is fine. But what Silver says is incorrect.

Comment: I stand corected. It does seems that Ord method does indeed support the WideChar (WideString) since in later versions (athleast Delphi XE3 and up) it returns a result of Smallint but the documentation still says that the return value of this method is Byte (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Ord) which would suggests only AnsiChar (AnsiString) support. I gues Embarcadero didn't update their documentaion acordingly when they updated the method itself.

Comment: @SilverWarior, this is yet another Borkadero's content bug, check out the description, it states the dimension of result correctly. `Ord` worked with `WideChar` from the very beginning. Actually, no special support for `WideChar` type needed, because it is an ordinal type.

Comment: @FreeConsulting Well I already opened an isue for this on new embarcadero quality center so perhaps the documentation on this will be fixed in some future version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a case statement to perform the encoding.

```
function EncodedChar(C: Char): Byte;
begin
  case C of
  'A'..'Z':
    Result := 1 + ord(C) - ord('A');
  ' ':
    Result := ???;
  ',':
    Result := ???;
  ... // more cases here
  else
    raise ECannotEncodeThisCharacter.Create(...);
  end;
end;
```

Encode a string with a `for` loop:

```
function EncodedString(const S: string): TBytes;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(S));
  for i := 1 to Length(S) do begin
    // dynamic arrays are 0-based, strings are 1-based, go figure!
    Result[i-1] := EncodedChar(S[i]);
  end;
end;
```